# MySQL load NULL values from CSV data

Tags: mysql, csv, load-data-infile

I have a file that can contain from 3 to 4 columns of numerical values which are separated by comma. Empty fields are defined with the exception when they are at the end of the row:

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,,5
1,2,3
```

The following table was created in MySQL:

```
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type   | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| one   | int(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| two   | int(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| three | int(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| four  | int(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
| five  | int(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       | 
+-------+--------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I am trying to load the data using MySQL LOAD command:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/testdata.txt' INTO TABLE moo FIELDS 
TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\n";
```

The resulting table:

```
+------+------+-------+------+------+
| one  | two  | three | four | five |
+------+------+-------+------+------+
|    1 |    2 |     3 |    4 |    5 | 
|    1 |    2 |     3 |    0 |    5 | 
|    1 |    2 |     3 | NULL | NULL | 
+------+------+-------+------+------+
```

The problem lies with the fact that when a field is empty in the raw data and is not defined, MySQL for some reason does not use the columns default value (which is NULL) and uses zero. NULL is used correctly when the field is missing alltogether.

Unfortunately, I have to be able to distinguish between NULL and 0 at this stage so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
S.

edit

The output of SHOW WARNINGS:

```
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Level   | Code | Message                                                |
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Warning | 1366 | Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'four' at row 2 | 
| Warning | 1261 | Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns             | 
| Warning | 1261 | Row 3 doesn't contain data for all columns             | 
+---------+------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: With data schema changes like that I would use [d6tstack](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack) which aligns all columns before running `LOAD DATA`. See [d6tstack SQL examples](https://github.com/d6t/d6tstack/blob/master/examples-sql.ipynb) section on data schema changes.

Answer (score 232, accepted):

This will do what you want. It reads the fourth field into a local variable, and then sets the actual field value to NULL, if the local variable ends up containing an empty string:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/testdata.txt'
INTO TABLE moo
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
(one, two, three, @vfour, five)
SET four = NULLIF(@vfour,'')
;
```

If they're all possibly empty, then you'd read them all into variables and have multiple SET statements, like this:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/testdata.txt'
INTO TABLE moo
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
(@vone, @vtwo, @vthree, @vfour, @vfive)
SET
one = NULLIF(@vone,''),
two = NULLIF(@vtwo,''),
three = NULLIF(@vthree,''),
four = NULLIF(@vfour,'')
;
```

Comment: Theoretically, I suppose - but it's all in-memory, and only holding tiny amounts of data per row, so I would image it would be infinitesimal; but you should test it if you think it might be a problem.

Comment: I really like this answer.  Users can see empty strings `''` when they download a csv (using `IFNULL(Col,'')` in `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` query) for excel but then uploads accept them as null vs having to deal with `\N` in the csv.  Thanks!

Comment: for dates I used 'NULLIF(STR_TO_DATE(@date1, "%d/%m/%Y"), "0000-00-00")'

Comment: I have a csv file that contains zeros `0` that should be converted to `NULL` (because it is not possible to have zero value for the data in question) and also empty strings. How to make sure that both zeros and empty strings are converted to `NULL`?

Comment: If the zero values and empty strings are in separate columns, then just do the above for the empty strings, and something like this for the zeros: `nullif(@vone, 0)`.

Comment: If they're both in the same column - i.e. a single source column that can contain either zero or empty strings, then you'll probably need to nest the `nullif` calls.

Comment: @Blacksonic I am performing 10 `nullif()` operations resulting in an 8.7% increased import time.  I was importing 300k records in 10 seconds. Import time increased to around 11 seconds with the added `nullif()` conditions

Comment: How to do this without mentioning specific columns? just for all?

Comment: what if you have 50 columns? setting up 50 columns seems overkill. is there a global way of telling Load function to just replace empty values with null?

Comment: Lemme guess does using `NULLIF` disqualify me from using `IGNORE 1 LINES`?

Answer (score 165):

[MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-null.html) says:

> When reading data with LOAD DATA
>   INFILE, empty or missing columns are
>   updated with ''. If you want a NULL 
>   value in a column, you should use \N
>   in the data file. The literal word
>   “NULL” may also be used under some
>   circumstances.

So you need to replace the blanks with \N like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5
1,2,3,\N,5
1,2,3
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I am sceptical to edit the raw source data but if this is the only way around it I will try it out.

Comment: I understand your scepticism, no one likes editing raw data, it just doesn't feel right. However, if you think about it for a minute, there has to be a way to distinguish between NULL and empty string. Should blank entries be translated to NULLs, you'd need a special sequence for empty string. It would nice to have a way how to tell MySQL how to treat blank entries though, something like LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/testdata.txt' INTO TABLE moo TREAT BLANKS AS NULL...

Comment: OK, but if you have `Fields enclosed by: "` is that `"\N"` of `"name",\N,"stuff"`

Comment: I can verify that at least for "phpMyAdmin 3.5.5" no style of `\N` is accepted as denoting `NULL`.
Instead use `NULL`, as in this example: `"name","age",NULL,"other","stuff"`

Comment: We have MySQL 5.5.46-0+deb8u1. I tried both NULL and \N, and only \N worked for us.

Comment: Is there some CSV standard that recognizes `\N` as a database NULL value? Or is `\N` some MySQL thing? Something feels corrupt about altering a `.csv` file into a format that contains non-CSV syntax, even if I'm gonna throw it away afterward. The solution mapping ad-hoc variables to columns seems extremely inelegant, but I think I want to take inelegant over corrupt.

Answer (score 8):

The behaviour is different depending upon the database configuration. In the strict mode this would throw an error else a warning.
Following query may be used for identifying the database configuration.

```
mysql> show variables like 'sql_mode';
```

Comment: Thanks! I was scratching my head trying to work out why importing a CSV with empty columns I'd successfully imported on the production server yesterday wasn't working on my brand-new local installation - this was the answer in my case!

Answer (score 5):

Preprocess your input CSV to replace blank entries with \N.

Attempt at a regex: s/,,/,\n,/g and s/,$/,\N/g

Good luck.

Comment: This regex partially works, it doesn't solve sequential blank entries, for example ,,,, will be ,\n,,\n,
Should be usable if you run it twice

Comment: Will summarize the answer and previous comment. Following  worked for me, in the order:   
sed -i 's/,,/,\N/g'    $file,  
sed -i 's/,,/,/g'        $file,
sed -i 's/\N,$/\N/g' $file,

Comment: I would like to do this, but I am not clear on how you are running this regex. If you are using MySQL to run this against the file this would be the best solution. But you don't say and I don't want to spend a bunch of time googling how to do something that may not be possible.

Answer (score 4):

**show variables**

`` Show variables like "`secure_file_priv`"; ``

Note: keep your csv file in location given by the above command.

```
create table assessments (course_code varchar(5),batch_code varchar(7),id_assessment int, assessment_type varchar(10), date int , weight int);
```

Note: here the '`date`' column has some blank values in the csv file.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Uploads/assessments.csv' 
INTO TABLE assessments
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
IGNORE 1 ROWS 
(course_code,batch_code,id_assessment,assessment_type,@date,weight)
SET date = IF(@date = '', NULL, @date);
```

Answer (score 1):

(variable1, @variable2, ..)
SET variable2 = nullif(@variable2, '' or ' ') >> you can put any condition

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment on https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968530/10376320

Answer (score 1):

Converted the input file to include `\N` for the blank column data using the below sed command in UNix terminal:

`sed -i 's/,,/,\\N,/g' $file_name`

and then use `LOAD DATA INFILE` command to load to mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can firstly read the file in pandas as pandas dataframe and then wherever you want the values to be NULL , there you can replace the empty values with string 'NULL' using replace function `(dataframe_name.replace(value_to_be_replaced,'NULL')` and save the new dataframe in .csv foramt using to_csv function.

After this when you will import the csv file into MySQL using :

1. Connect to the server with local-infile system variable :

> mysql --local-infile=1 -u root -p

2. When you are inside MySQL server on cmd, set the global variables by using this command:

> SET GLOBAL local_infile=1;

3. Use your Database and load the file into the table:

> use

4. Load the file

> load data local infile '<path_to_file>' into table <table_name>
> columns terminated by "," optionally enclosed by "'" ignore 1 lines.

Then all the NULL values in the dataset will be recognised as NULL only.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The chosen solution is a way - however there is a difference between null and empty space.  For numbers it works.  The earlier solutions allow you to keep the null when loading in.

It really is a shame that sed hasn't implemented PCRE.  That would give it look ahead, and a slew of other capabilities. But the perl solution is:

```
perl -pi -e 's/,(?=,|$)/,\\\\N/g' /my/file
```

*Note: the i means in place editing.  Haven't tested it, but it creates a neat solution if it works.*

It works because the lookahead doesn't consume a character, and so the forward match is ready for the next match.

Please test, and of course, your shell escapes may need tweaking.

Answer (score -2):

MySQL converts empty fields into empty string `''`, hence why the error when inserting numerical fields, since the conversion from string to INT is not a thing. Even when the INT field in the create table is DEFAULT NULL.
The straightforward solution would be to preprocess the csv and insert `\N` (not `\n`) as NULL fields.
This can be done quickly with:

```
sed -i 's/,,/,\\N,/g file.csv'
sed -i 's/,,/,\\N,/g file.csv'
```

It is important to do it twice because consecutive blank fields will be skipped, since the second separator of a blank field is also the first separator of the next field, and it will be skipped after the first substitution.

In other words, if you use only one command, `something,,,,SomethingElse` will be converted to `something,\N,,\N,SomethingElse`.

Maybe there is a smarter way to do it with a more advanced command but this works just fine. You can loop through all csvs in a dir and run the command twice for each file.
([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html))

Comment: this command is not working