# Getting a mysql Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column when doing a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql, sql, file-io, load

I'm getting a mysql Error Code:

> 1265. Data truncated for column when doing a LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE.

Running MySQL on a Win7 PC. Using the SQL Workbench, I have a new table called full_daily_data.  I created it with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE full_daily_data ( 
Run_Date DATE,
Run_Time TIME,
Bar_Num INT,
Symbol VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
Trade_Date DATE,
Day_Open FLOAT,
Day_High FLOAT,
Day_Low FLOAT,
Day_Close FLOAT,
Prior_Open FLOAT,
Prior_High FLOAT,
Prior_Low FLOAT,
Prior_Close FLOAT,
Pct_UpDn_Since_Open FLOAT,
Pct_UpDn_Since_PrClose FLOAT,
Open_Gap FLOAT,
Open_Gap_Pct FLOAT,
Open_Gap_Filled_Intraday FLOAT,
Open_Gap_Filled_With_Close FLOAT,
Open_As_Pct_InOut_Prior_Days_Range FLOAT,
Close_As_Pct_InOut_Prior_Days_Range FLOAT,
Volume FLOAT,
5_Day_Avg_Volume FLOAT,
10_Day_Avg_Volume FLOAT,
20_Day_Avg_Volume FLOAT,
90_Day_Avg_Volume FLOAT,
Volume_As_Pct_Of_5Day_Avg FLOAT,
20_Day_Volatility_StdDev FLOAT,
20_Day_Volatility_Pct_ATR FLOAT,
3_Day_ATR FLOAT,
14_Day_ATR FLOAT,
3_Day_Avg_IDay_Range FLOAT,
14_Day_Avg_IDay_Range FLOAT,
Range_As_Pct_Of_14_Day_Avg_IDay_Range FLOAT,
Consec_Inside_Bars INT,
Consec_Outside_Bars INT,
Days_To_3rd_Friday INT,
Consec_Up_Bars INT,
Consec_Dn_Bars INT,
Key_Reversal_Flag VARCHAR(15),
One_Year_High FLOAT,
One_Year_Low FLOAT,
Pct_In_1Yr_HighLow_Range FLOAT,
Six_Week_High FLOAT,
Six_Week_Low FLOAT,
Pct_In_6Wk_HighLow_Range FLOAT,
20_Day_MA FLOAT,
50_Day_MA FLOAT,
200_Day_MA FLOAT,
Dist_20_From_50_As_Pct_Price FLOAT,
Dist_50_From_200_As_Pct_Price FLOAT,
Dist_From_20_As_Pct_Price FLOAT,
Dist_From_50_As_Pct_Price FLOAT,
Dist_From_200_As_Pct_Price FLOAT,
20_MA_Slope FLOAT,
50_MA_Slope FLOAT,
Stoch_FastK FLOAT,
Stoch_FastD FLOAT,
Stoch_SlowK FLOAT,
Stoch_SlowD FLOAT,
Ultimate_Osc FLOAT,
RSI FLOAT,
OBV FLOAT,
Vol_As_Pct_Of_OBV FLOAT,
CCI FLOAT,
ADX FLOAT,
DMI FLOAT,
DMIPlus FLOAT,
DMIMinus FLOAT,
Lin_Reg_Slope_ADX FLOAT,
Lin_Reg_Slope_DMI FLOAT,
MACD FLOAT,
MACD_Avg_Diff FLOAT,
MACD_Slope FLOAT,
Lin_Regr_Slope FLOAT,
Momentum FLOAT,
Williams_PctR FLOAT,
BB_2_StdDev_Pct_Range FLOAT,
14_Day_MFI FLOAT,
Pct_In_Pivots FLOAT,
Standard_Deviation FLOAT,
Market_Cap FLOAT,
Total_Assets FLOAT,
Total_Liabilities FLOAT,
Total_Long_Term_Debt FLOAT,
Net_Income_Before_Extra_Items FLOAT,
Net_Income FLOAT,
Total_Common_Shares_Outstanding FLOAT,
Total_Equity FLOAT,
Net_Sales FLOAT,
Total_Revenue FLOAT,
Basic_EPS_Including_Extra_Items FLOAT,
Basic_EPS_Excluding_Extra_Items FLOAT,
Capital_Expenditures FLOAT,
Gross_Margin FLOAT,
Gross_Profit FLOAT,
Net_Cash_Beg_Balance FLOAT,
Net_Cash_End_Bal FLOAT,
Operating_Income FLOAT,
Revenue FLOAT,
Total_Debt FLOAT,
Basic_Normalized_EPS FLOAT,
Intangibles_Net FLOAT,
Net_Cash_Per_Rev FLOAT,
Net_Cash_Per_Mkt_Cap FLOAT,
Net_Cash_Per_LTDebt FLOAT,
LTDebt_Per_Revenue FLOAT,
LTDebt_Per_Mkt_Cap FLOAT,
PRIMARY KEY (Symbol,Trade_Date)
);
```

Now I'm trying to load data into it from a .csv file.  This is the script I'm using for the load:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Trading\\Tools\\Research Tools - Mine\\PriceDB Related\\Data Grabbed From TS for Upload\\GrabbedData - Short Test.csv'
REPLACE INTO TABLE full_daily_data_1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(Run_Date,
Run_Time,
Bar_Num,
Symbol,
Trade_Date,
Day_Open,
Day_High,
Day_Low,
Day_Close,
Prior_Open,
Prior_High,
Prior_Low,
Prior_Close,
Pct_UpDn_Since_Open,
Pct_UpDn_Since_PrClose,
Open_Gap,
Open_Gap_Pct,
Open_Gap_Filled_Intraday,
Open_Gap_Filled_With_Close,
Open_As_Pct_InOut_Prior_Days_Range,
Close_As_Pct_InOut_Prior_Days_Range,
Volume,
5_Day_Avg_Volume,
10_Day_Avg_Volume,
20_Day_Avg_Volume,
90_Day_Avg_Volume,
Volume_As_Pct_Of_5Day_Avg,
20_Day_Volatility_StdDev,
20_Day_Volatility_Pct_ATR,
3_Day_ATR,
14_Day_ATR,
3_Day_Avg_IDay_Range,
14_Day_Avg_IDay_Range,
Range_As_Pct_Of_14_Day_Avg_IDay_Range,
Consec_Inside_Bars,
Consec_Outside_Bars,
Days_To_3rd_Friday,
Consec_Up_Bars,
Consec_Dn_Bars,
Key_Reversal_Flag,
One_Year_High,
One_Year_Low,
Pct_In_1Yr_HighLow_Range,
Six_Week_High,
Six_Week_Low,
Pct_In_6Wk_HighLow_Range,
20_Day_MA,
50_Day_MA,
200_Day_MA,
Dist_20_From_50_As_Pct_Price,
Dist_50_From_200_As_Pct_Price,
Dist_From_20_As_Pct_Price,
Dist_From_50_As_Pct_Price,
Dist_From_200_As_Pct_Price,
20_MA_Slope,
50_MA_Slope,
Stoch_FastK,
Stoch_FastD,
Stoch_SlowK,
Stoch_SlowD,
Ultimate_Osc,
RSI,
OBV,
Vol_As_Pct_Of_OBV,
CCI,
ADX,
DMI,
DMIPlus,
DMIMinus,
Lin_Reg_Slope_ADX,
Lin_Reg_Slope_DMI,
MACD,
MACD_Avg_Diff,
MACD_Slope,
Lin_Regr_Slope,
Momentum,
Williams_PctR,
BB_2_StdDev_Pct_Range,
14_Day_MFI,
Pct_In_Pivots,
Standard_Deviation,
Market_Cap,
Total_Assets,
Total_Liabilities,
Total_Long_Term_Debt,
Net_Income_Before_Extra_Items,
Net_Income,
Total_Common_Shares_Outstanding,
Total_Equity,
Net_Sales,
Total_Revenue,
Basic_EPS_Including_Extra_Items,
Basic_EPS_Excluding_Extra_Items,
Capital_Expenditures,
Gross_Margin,
Gross_Profit,
Net_Cash_Beg_Balance,
Net_Cash_End_Bal,
Operating_Income,
Revenue,
Total_Debt,
Basic_Normalized_EPS,
Intangibles_Net,
Net_Cash_Per_Rev,
Net_Cash_Per_Mkt_Cap,
Net_Cash_Per_LTDebt,
LTDebt_Per_Revenue,
LTDebt_Per_Mkt_Cap
) ;
```

Below is the .csv file contents that I'm loading (about 30 lines).  The place that it occurs at is the 90_Day_Avg_Volume column which is the first field that has no data in it.  I thought that this should be OK. Any idea why I'm getting this error?

```
Run_Date,Run_Time,Bar_Num,Symbol,Trade_Date,Day_Open,Day_High,Day_Low,Day_Close,Prior_Open,Prior_High,Prior_Low,Prior_Close,Pct_UpDn_Since_Open,Pct_UpDn_Since_PrClose,Open_Gap,Open_Gap_Pct,Open_Gap_Filled_Intraday,Open_Gap_Filled_With_Close,Open_As_Pct_InOut_Prior_Days_Range,Close_As_Pct_InOut_Prior_Days_Range,Volume:FLOAT,5_Day_Avg_Volume,10_Day_Avg_Volume,20_Day_Avg_Volume,90_Day_Avg_Volume,Volume_As_Pct_Of_5Day_Avg,20_Day_Volatility_StdDev,20_Day_Volatility_Pct_ATR,3_Day_ATR,14_Day_ATR,3_Day_Avg_IDay_Range,14_Day_Avg_IDay_Range,Range_As_Pct_Of_14_Day_Avg_IDay_Range,Consec_Inside_Bars,Consec_Outside_Bars,Days_To_3rd_Friday,Consec_Up_Bars,Consec_Dn_Bars,Key_Reversal_Flag,One_Year_High,One_Year_Low,Pct_In_1Yr_HighLow_Range,Six_Week_High,Six_Week_Low,Pct_In_6Wk_HighLow_Range,20_Day_MA,50_Day_MA,200_Day_MA,Dist_20_From_50_As_Pct_Price,Dist_50_From_200_As_Pct_Price,Dist_From_20_As_Pct_Price,Dist_From_50_As_Pct_Price,Dist_From_200_As_Pct_Price,20_MA_Slope:FLOAT,50_MA_Slope:FLOAT,Stoch_FastK,Stoch_FastD,Stoch_SlowK,Stoch_SlowD,Ultimate_Osc,RSI,OBV,Vol_As_Pct_Of_OBV,CCI,ADX,DMI,DMIPlus,DMIMinus,Lin_Reg_Slope_ADX,Lin_Reg_Slope_DMI,MACD,MACD_Avg_Diff,MACD_Slope,Lin_Regr_Slope,Momentum,Williams_PctR,BB_2_StdDev_Pct_Range,14_Day_MFI,Pct_In_Pivots,Standard_Deviation,Market_Cap,Total_Assets,Total_Liabilities,Total_Long_Term_Debt,Net_Income_Before_Extra_Items,Net_Income,Total_Common_Shares_Outstanding,Total_Equity,Net_Sales,Total_Revenue,Basic_EPS_Including_Extra_Items,Basic_EPS_Excluding_Extra_Items,Capital_Expenditures,Gross_Margin,Gross_Profit,Net_Cash_Beg_Balance,Net_Cash_End_Balance,Operating_Income,Revenue,Total_Debt,Basic_Normalized_EPS,Intangibles_Net,Net_Cash_Per_Rev,Net_Cash_Per_Mkt_Cap,Net_Cash_Per_LTDebt,LTDebt_Per_Revenue,LTDebt_Per_Mkt_Cap
2013/02/13,10:35,1,A,2005/11/15,32.79,32.93,32.43,32.51,30.9,31.37,30.88,31,-0.0085,0.0487,-0.1,-0.0032,0,0,3.898,3.3265,16589515,5822218,4133125,3300523,,2.8493,0.2207,0.0594,0.91,0.63,0.43,0.52,0.9615,0,0,3,0,0,,32.93,32.43,0.16,32.93,32.43,0.16,30.27,,,,,0.0722,,,0.1169,,91.04,91.04,91.04,91.04,0.66,87.87,16589515,1,179.51,50.88,50.88,44.13,14.37,5.451,5.451,0,0,0,0.26,3.3,91.04,1.0733,84.71,0.77,1,16352.53,6751,2670,0,-17,26,503,4081,1407,1407,0.05,-0.03,-139,49.4,695,2315,2226,70,1407,0,-0.03,38,1.58,0.14,,0,0
2013/02/13,10:35,2,A,2005/11/16,32.27,32.6,32.2,32.27,32.79,32.93,32.43,32.51,0,-0.0074,0.28,0.0086,1,0,-0.32,-0.32,4509130,6054180,4397458,3325194,,0.7448,0.2213,0.0574,0.94,0.62,0.46,0.52,0.7682,0,0,2,0,0,,32.6,32.2,0.175,32.6,32.2,0.175,30.42,,,,,0.057,,,0.1314,,85.93,89.34,89.34,90.48,0.62,82.96,12080385,0.3733,142.38,47.4,43.93,42.06,16.39,8.713,8.341,-0.0191,-0.0153,-0.0038,0.38,2.11,85.93,0.9436,79.35,0.35,1.07,16231.81,6751,2670,0,-17,26,503,4081,1407,1407,0.05,-0.03,-139,49.4,695,2315,2226,70,1407,0,-0.03,38,1.58,0.14,,0,0
2013/02/13,10:35,3,A,2005/11/17,32.22,32.78,32.19,32.75,32.27,32.6,32.2,32.27,0.0164,0.0149,0,0,1,1,0.05,1.375,6216584,6692438,4860661,3497155,,0.9289,0.2155,0.0547,0.97,0.59,0.5,0.49,1.2041,0,1,1,0,0,,32.78,32.19,0.9492,32.78,32.19,0.9492,30.6,,,,,0.0665,,,0.1543,,95.23,90.42,90.42,90.27,0.65,84.79,18296969,0.3398,143.47,46.94,46.02,41.26,15.25,10.233,9.886,0.0044,0.0066,-0.001,0.47,2.48,95.23,0.9834,84.85,0.77,1.14,16473.25,6751,2670,0,-17,26,503,4081,1407,1407,0.05,-0.03,-139,49.4,695,2315,2226,70,1407,0,-0.03,38,1.58,0.14,,0,0
2013/02/13,10:35,4,A,2005/11/18,32.78,32.93,32.58,32.89,32.22,32.78,32.19,32.75,0.0034,0.0043,-0.53,-0.0162,1,0,1,1.1864,5226902,7259629,5166406,3640205,,0.72,0.2154,0.0522,0.45,0.54,0.45,0.44,0.8046,0,0,28,0,0,,32.93,32.19,0.9459,32.93,32.19,0.9459,30.78,,,,,0.0643,,,0.1713,,98.61,92.23,92.23,90.66,0.66,85.29,23523871,0.2222,146.68,47.15,47.77,41.33,14.61,10.098,9.975,0.0339,0.0289,0.0072,0.4,2.1,98.61,0.9491,85.45,0.47,1.2,16543.67,6751,2670,0,-17,26,503,4081,1407,1407,0.05,-0.03,-139,49.4,695,2315,2226,70,1407,0,-0.03,38,1.58,0.13,,0,0
2013/02/13,10:35,5,A,2005/11/21,32.6,33.06,32.59,32.96,32.78,32.93,32.58,32.89,0.011,0.0021,-0.11,-0.0033,1,1,0.0571,1.0857,4322231,7372872,5420338,3767038,,0.5862,0.2155,0.0502,0.47,0.53,0.47,0.43,1.0948,0,0,25,0,0,,33.06,32.19,0.8851,33.06,32.19,0.8851,30.96,,,,,0.0607,,,0.1745,,96.49,96.63,96.63,93.09,0.68,85.54,27846102,0.1552,139.87,47.58,49.31,40.54,13.76,8.326,8.522,0.0622,0.0458,0.0178,0.15,2.15,96.49,0.9104,86.04,0.68,1.25,16578.88,6751,2670,0,-17,26,503,4081,1407,1407,0.05,-0.03,-139,49.4,695,2315,2226,70,1407,0,-0.03,38,1.58,0.13,,0,0
2013/02/13,10:35,6,A,2005/11/22,32.84,33.73,32.84,33.51,32.6,33.06,32.59,32.96,0.0204,0.0167,-0.36,-0.0109,1,1,0.5319,1.9574,4083858,4871741,5346979,3835249,,0.8383,0.2177,0.0483,0.57,0.54,0.57,0.44,2.0293,0,0,24,0,0,,33.73,32.19,0.8571,33.73,32.19,0.8571,31.17,,,,,0.071,,,0.1863,,92.95,95.93,95.93,94.93,0.68,87.39,31929960,0.1279,151.6,49.06,56.42,44.2,12.31,5.012,6.07,0.1276,0.0889,0.0351,0.27,2.61,92.95,0.9574,86.58,0.76,1.31,16855.53,6751,2670,0,-17,26,503,4081,1407,1407,0.05,-0.03,-139,49.4,695,2315,2226,70,1407,0,-0.03,38,1.58,0.13,,0,0
2013/02/13,10:35,7,A,2005/11/23,33.4,33.72,33.4,33.59,32.84,33.73,32.84,33.51,0.0057,0.0024,-0.67,-0.02,1,1,0.6292,0.8427,2666357,4503186,5278683,3877272,,0.5921,0.2134,0.0462,0.56,0.54,0.56,0.43,0.7381,1,0,23,0,0,,33.73,32.19,0.9091,33.73,32.19,0.9091,31.39,,,,,0.0657,,,0.1957,,95.51,94.94,94.94,95.83,0.71,87.63,34596317,0.0771,137.99,50.11,56.42,42.47,11.83,0.058,1.604,0.1838,0.116,0.0452,0.23,2.59,95.51,0.9236,86.84,0.28,1.33,16895.77,6751,2670,0,-17,26,503,4081,1407,1407,0.05,-0.03,-139,49.4,695,2315,2226,70,1407,0,-0.03,38,1.58,0.13,,0,0
2013/02/13,10:35,8,A,2005/11/25,33.59,33.7,33.55,33.63,33.4,33.72,33.4,33.59,0.0012,0.0012,-0.19,-0.0057,0,0,0.5938,0.7188,1139222,3487714,5090076,3866218,,0.3266,0.2009,0.0441,0.45,0.52,0.45,0.42,0.3565,2,0,21,0,0,,33.73,32.19,0.9351,33.73,32.19,0.9351,31.63,,,,,0.0595,,,0.212,,96.79,95.09,95.09,95.32,0.69,87.76,35735539,0.0319,122.37,50.9,56.42,41.64,11.6,0.668,2.39,0.2288,0.1289,0.0511,0.21,2.56,96.79,0.9021,86.65,0.33,1.28,16915.89,6751,2670,0,-17,26,503,4081,1407,1407,0.05,-0.03,-139,49.4,695,2315,2226,70,1407,0,-0.03,38,1.58,0.13,,0,0
2013/02/13,10:35,9,A,2005/11/28,33.54,33.59,33.37,33.59,33.59,33.7,33.55,33.63,0.0015,-0.0012,-0.04,-0.0012,0,0,-0.0667,0.2667,3498646,3142063,5200846,3914710,,1.1135,0.2017,0.0423,0.24,0.51,0.23,0.41,0.5432,0,0,18,0,0,,33.73,32.19,0.9091,33.73,32.19,0.9091,31.85,,,,,0.0518,,,0.2234,,95.21,95.85,95.85,95.29,0.74,86.79,32236893,0.1085,103.29,50.73,49.39,40.19,13.62,0.763,1.232,0.2584,0.1267,0.0493,0.14,2.47,95.21,0.8682,84.11,0.79,1.21,16895.77,6751,2670,0,-17,26,503,4081,1407,1407,0.05,-0.03,-139,49.4,695,2315,2226,70,1407,0,-0.03,38,1.58,0.13,,0,0
2013/02/13,10:36,346,AA,1999/07/26,29.5,30.22,29.25,29.31,30.75,31.06,29.75,29.75,-0.0064,-0.0148,1,0.0336,1,0,-0.1908,-0.3359,2070600,2095480,2892060,3199040,4231589,0.9881,0.246,0.0346,1.09,0.87,1.09,0.8,1.2179,0,0,25,0,2,,33.97,14.48,0.7609,33.97,27.22,2.197,30.82,30.81,23.62,0.0003,0.2417,-0.0509,-0.0505,0.1912,-0.0397,-0.0371,2.32,15.3,15.3,18.88,0.35,39.06,83682400,0.0247,-175.64,12.28,2.46,23.04,24.2,-0.802,-1.128,-0.3041,-0.1894,-0.0406,-0.21,-1.88,2.32,-0.0905,41.96,0.3,0.66,21493.989,17098.4,11007,2807.6,240,240,733,6091.4,4032.7,4075.5,0.33,0.33,-387.7,22.13,892.3,342.2,242.7,431.6,4032.7,3370.7,0.33,119.8,0.06,0.01,-3.67,-0.02,0
2013/02/13,10:36,347,AA,1999/07/27,29.38,30.63,29.38,30.31,29.5,30.22,29.25,29.31,0.0317,0.0341,0.19,0.0065,0,0,0.134,1.0928,3260200,2344160,2865480,3206870,4231138,1.3908,0.2739,0.034,1.2,0.85,1.18,0.82,1.5231,0,0,24,1,0,,33.97,14.48,0.8122,33.97,27.22,2.3452,30.76,30.79,23.68,-0.0013,0.2427,-0.0153,-0.0165,0.2261,-0.0514,-0.031,40.93,15.25,15.25,16.31,0.43,47.52,86942600,0.0375,-95.34,11.7,4.07,23.79,21.93,-0.767,-0.31,-0.2858,-0.1369,-0.0369,-0.09,-1,40.93,0.3203,53,0.65,0.64,22227.322,17098.4,11007,2807.6,240,240,733,6091.4,4032.7,4075.5,0.33,0.33,-387.7,22.13,892.3,342.2,242.7,431.6,4032.7,3370.7,0.33,119.8,0.06,0.01,-3.67,-0.02,0
2013/02/13,10:36,348,AA,1999/07/28,30.13,30.81,29.88,30.75,29.38,30.63,29.38,30.31,0.0206,0.0145,-0.93,-0.0307,1,1,0.6,1.096,1857600,2391120,2688000,3202190,4214942,0.7769,0.2795,0.0334,1.07,0.85,1.05,0.82,1.1332,0,0,23,2,0,,33.97,14.48,0.8348,33.97,27.22,2.4104,30.72,30.78,23.74,-0.0019,0.2323,0.001,-0.0009,0.2313,-0.0614,-0.0258,57.92,33.72,33.72,21.42,0.48,50.76,88800200,0.0209,-38.61,11.35,6.88,23.5,20.47,-0.675,0.519,-0.2331,-0.0673,-0.0217,0.06,-0.34,57.92,0.5121,50.11,0.55,0.62,22549.989,17098.4,11007,2807.6,240,240,733,6091.4,4032.7,4075.5,0.33,0.33,-387.7,22.13,892.3,342.2,242.7,431.6,4032.7,3370.7,0.33,119.8,0.06,0.01,-3.67,-0.02,0
2013/02/13,10:36,349,AA,1999/07/29,30.25,30.44,29.88,30.09,30.13,30.81,29.88,30.75,-0.0053,-0.0215,-0.62,-0.0202,0,0,0.3978,0.2258,1595200,2263200,2500460,3137220,4204020,0.7048,0.2833,0.0338,1.04,0.86,0.91,0.81,0.6877,0,0,22,0,1,,33.97,14.48,0.8009,33.97,28.25,2.729,30.68,30.77,23.79,-0.0029,0.2269,-0.0191,-0.022,0.2049,-0.0591,-0.0195,36.84,45.58,45.58,31.52,0.45,46.16,87205000,0.0183,-79.39,11.03,6.88,22.02,19.19,-0.577,0.695,-0.2418,-0.0608,0.003,0.21,-0.91,36.84,0.2599,43.53,0.34,0.63,22065.989,17098.4,11007,2807.6,240,240,733,6091.4,4032.7,4075.5,0.33,0.33,-387.7,22.13,892.3,342.2,242.7,431.6,4032.7,3370.7,0.33,119.8,0.06,0.01,-3.67,-0.02,0
2013/02/13,10:36,350,AA,1999/07/30,30,30.09,29.56,29.94,30.25,30.44,29.88,30.09,-0.002,-0.005,0.16,0.0053,0,0,0.2143,0.1071,2109000,2178520,2174520,3065440,4198836,0.9681,0.2754,0.0332,0.78,0.85,0.67,0.8,0.6637,0,0,21,0,2,,33.97,14.48,0.7932,33.97,29.16,3.2141,30.6,30.76,23.85,-0.0051,0.2296,-0.022,-0.0271,0.2025,-0.052,-0.0141,31.51,42.92,42.92,40.74,0.47,45.16,85096000,0.0248,-106.77,10.3,0.79,21.15,20.82,-0.53,0.076,-0.2578,-0.0615,0.0136,0.1,-0.97,31.51,0.2263,43.6,0.56,0.62,21955.989,17098.4,11007,2807.6,240,240,733,6091.4,4032.7,4075.5,0.33,0.33,-387.7,22.13,892.3,342.2,242.7,431.6,4032.7,3370.7,0.33,119.8,0.06,0.01,-3.67,-0.02,0
2013/02/13,10:36,351,AA,1999/08/02,30.09,30.88,29.81,30.72,30,30.09,29.56,29.94,0.0209,0.0261,0.06,0.002,1,0,1,2.1887,1790400,2122480,2108980,3028090,4197444,0.8435,0.2922,0.0325,0.82,0.89,0.72,0.85,1.2641,0,0,18,1,0,,33.97,14.48,0.8332,33.97,29.25,3.4407,30.57,30.79,23.91,-0.0073,0.2297,0.005,-0.0023,0.2275,-0.0495,-0.0036,67.12,45.05,45.05,44.51,0.48,51.1,86886400,0.0206,-17.86,10.55,13.83,25.32,19.17,-0.432,0.854,-0.2052,-0.0071,0.0136,0,0.34,67.12,0.5652,50.75,0.82,0.59,22527.989,17098.4,11007,2807.6,240,240,733,6091.4,4032.7,4075.5,0.33,0.33,-387.7,22.13,892.3,342.2,242.7,431.6,4032.7,3370.7,0.33,119.8,0.06,0.01,-3.67,-0.02,0
2013/02/13,10:36,352,AA,1999/08/03,30.72,31.22,30.5,31.06,30.09,30.88,29.81,30.72,0.0111,0.0111,-0.63,-0.0205,0,0,0.8505,1.1682,2021800,1874800,2109480,2883520,4192716,1.0784,0.2891,0.0317,0.77,0.91,0.77,0.87,0.831,0,0,17,2,0,,33.97,14.48,0.8507,33.97,29.25,3.5127,30.53,30.81,23.97,-0.0092,0.2227,0.0173,0.0081,0.2309,-0.0496,0.0083,82.65,60.43,60.43,49.46,0.56,53.47,88908200,0.0227,69.7,11.14,18.78,26.51,18.13,-0.242,2.228,-0.1345,0.0508,0.0234,0.13,0.53,82.65,0.7611,48.4,0.48,0.52,22777.322,17098.4,11007,2807.6,240,240,733,6091.4,4032.7,4075.5,0.33,0.33,-387.7,22.13,892.3,342.2,242.7,431.6,4032.7,3370.7,0.33,119.8,0.06,0.01,-3.67,-0.02,0
2013/02/13,10:36,353,AA,1999/08/04,30.94,32.59,30.94,32,30.72,31.22,30.5,31.06,0.0343,0.0303,-0.34,-0.0109,1,1,0.6111,2.0833,3546400,2212560,2301840,2733780,4197251,1.6028,0.2755,0.0318,1.15,0.98,1.15,0.95,1.7434,0,0,16,3,0,,33.97,14.48,0.8989,33.97,29.25,3.7119,30.59,30.85,24.03,-0.0082,0.2195,0.0453,0.0371,0.2566,-0.0244,0.0212,82.34,78.11,78.11,61.19,0.62,59.33,92454600,0.0384,187.53,12.84,34.98,33.19,15.99,0.091,4.41,-0.0027,0.1462,0.0602,0.49,1.5,82.34,1.0842,58.81,0.76,0.62,23466.655,17098.4,11007,2807.6,240,240,733,6091.4,4032.7,4075.5,0.33,0.33,-387.7,22.13,892.3,342.2,242.7,431.6,4032.7,3370.7,0.33,119.8,0.06,0.01,-3.67,-0.02,0
2013/02/13,10:37,539,AAN,2009/04/09,19.54,20.33,19.19,19.41,18.43,19.19,18.39,19.12,-0.0067,0.0152,-0.69,-0.0361,0,0,1.4375,1.275,2514394,1483810,1498888,1480106,1402062,1.6946,0.4111,0.0455,0.86,0.93,0.84,0.9,1.2597,0,0,8,3,0,,20.33,10.07,0.9103,20.33,14.31,1.5515,17.25,16.32,16.77,0.0487,-0.0237,0.1131,0.1617,0.138,0.1546,0.0409,83.21,90.51,90.51,92.38,0.65,73.74,7546992,0.3332,159.48,20.41,51.2,33.47,10.8,1.349,3.802,0.7835,0.2487,0.0552,0.23,3.8,83.21,0.9584,68.44,0.47,1.21,1562.033,1233.27,471.73,114.82,21.01,21.08,80,761.54,391.13,404.89,0.26,0.26,-74.92,77.84,304.46,4.79,7.38,34.12,391.13,114.82,0.26,7.5,0.02,0,-0.1,-0.18,-0.05
2013/02/13,10:37,540,AAN,2009/04/13,19.4,19.75,19.03,19.66,19.54,20.33,19.19,19.41,0.0134,0.0129,0.13,0.0067,1,1,0.1842,0.4123,1296444,1569901,1504473,1483597,1407393,0.8258,0.411,0.0445,0.91,0.92,0.89,0.89,0.8051,0,0,4,4,0,,20.33,10.07,0.9347,20.33,14.31,1.593,17.4,16.4,16.78,0.0514,-0.0196,0.1164,0.1677,0.1481,0.1509,0.0567,87.77,89.15,89.15,91.02,0.66,75.13,8843436,0.1466,129.02,22.28,46.57,31.49,11.48,1.5,3.463,0.8493,0.2516,0.0625,0.34,4.03,87.77,0.9414,68.21,0.48,1.31,1582.152,1233.27,471.73,114.82,21.01,21.08,80,761.54,391.13,404.89,0.26,0.26,-74.92,77.84,304.46,4.79,7.38,34.12,391.13,114.82,0.26,7.5,0.02,0,-0.1,-0.18,-0.04
2013/02/13,10:37,541,AAN,2009/04/14,19.52,19.61,18.83,19.33,19.4,19.75,19.03,19.66,-0.0097,-0.0168,-0.26,-0.0132,0,0,0.6806,0.4167,1064467,1616283,1412678,1486683,1409051,0.6586,0.3994,0.0452,0.92,0.93,0.88,0.9,0.8619,0,0,3,0,1,,20.33,10.07,0.9025,20.33,14.31,1.5382,17.56,16.5,16.8,0.054,-0.0154,0.0899,0.144,0.1286,0.1552,0.0739,81.75,84.25,84.25,87.97,0.66,69.86,7778969,0.1368,103.54,23.6,40.77,29.33,12.34,1.627,3.276,0.8649,0.2137,0.0579,0.22,2.43,81.75,0.8376,68.11,0.57,1.34,1555.595,1233.27,471.73,114.82,21.01,21.08,80,761.54,391.13,404.89,0.26,0.26,-74.92,77.84,304.46,4.79,7.38,34.12,391.13,114.82,0.26,7.5,0.02,0,-0.1,-0.18,-0.05
2013/02/13,10:37,542,AAN,2009/04/15,19.36,19.93,19.12,19.4,19.52,19.61,18.83,19.33,0.0021,0.0036,0.19,0.0098,1,0,0.6795,0.7308,1434901,1641478,1384125,1518444,1404930,0.8742,0.3896,0.0448,0.79,0.9,0.77,0.87,0.9333,0,0,2,1,0,,20.33,10.07,0.9094,20.33,14.31,1.5498,17.7,16.6,16.82,0.0571,-0.0117,0.088,0.1451,0.1334,0.1519,0.0857,79.69,83.27,83.27,85.56,0.61,70.34,9213870,0.1557,104.97,25.1,44.55,30.01,11.51,1.696,2.586,0.8728,0.1773,0.04,0.05,2.48,79.69,0.8149,75.77,0.46,1.39,1561.228,1233.27,471.73,114.82,21.01,21.08,80,761.54,391.13,404.89,0.26,0.26,-74.92,77.84,304.46,4.79,7.38,34.12,391.13,114.82,0.26,7.5,0.02,0,-0.1,-0.18,-0.05
2013/02/13,10:37,543,AAN,2009/04/16,19.51,19.75,19.17,19.64,19.36,19.93,19.12,19.4,0.0067,0.0124,-0.04,-0.0021,1,0,0.4815,0.642,1297275,1521496,1396042,1469134,1405945,0.8526,0.3854,0.0436,0.74,0.84,0.72,0.82,0.703,1,0,1,2,0,,20.33,10.07,0.9327,20.33,14.31,1.5897,17.85,16.68,16.85,0.0608,-0.0088,0.0921,0.1528,0.144,0.1509,0.0905,82.71,81.35,81.35,82.96,0.63,71.97,10511145,0.1234,96.58,26.49,44.55,28.54,10.95,1.69,1.61,0.8882,0.1542,0.0233,0.02,1.81,82.71,0.8222,75.7,0.5,1.42,1580.542,1233.27,471.73,114.82,21.01,21.08,80,761.54,391.13,404.89,0.26,0.26,-74.92,77.84,304.46,4.79,7.38,34.12,391.13,114.82,0.26,7.5,0.02,0,-0.1,-0.18,-0.04
2013/02/13,10:37,544,AAN,2009/04/17,19.75,20.09,19.52,20.01,19.51,19.75,19.17,19.64,0.0132,0.0188,-0.13,-0.0066,1,0,1,1.4483,1020070,1222631,1353221,1424558,1410754,0.8343,0.38,0.042,0.65,0.84,0.65,0.82,0.6945,0,0,28,3,0,,20.33,10.07,0.9688,20.33,14.31,1.6512,18.04,16.77,16.87,0.0647,-0.0054,0.1005,0.1652,0.1598,0.1563,0.0898,91.6,84.33,84.33,82.98,0.64,74.32,11531215,0.0885,104.99,28.07,48.6,30.08,10.41,1.609,0.555,0.9197,0.1485,0.0164,0.1,2.24,91.6,0.8482,75.66,0.61,1.45,1610.318,1233.27,471.73,114.82,21.01,21.08,80,761.54,391.13,404.89,0.26,0.26,-74.92,77.84,304.46,4.79,7.38,34.12,391.13,114.82,0.26,7.5,0.02,0,-0.1,-0.18,-0.04
2013/02/13,10:37,545,AAN,2009/04/20,20,20.7,18.21,18.68,19.75,20.09,19.52,20.01,-0.066,-0.0665,-0.26,-0.013,1,0,0.8421,-1.4737,1213111,1205965,1387933,1427325,1414045,1.0059,0.4492,0.0494,1.21,0.92,1.21,0.9,2.7777,0,1,25,0,1,KEYREVERSALDN,20.7,10.07,0.81,20.7,14.31,1.3474,18.18,16.83,16.89,0.0673,-0.003,0.0251,0.0924,0.0894,0.1569,0.0833,42.78,73.26,73.26,79.65,0.49,56.13,10318104,0.1176,62.55,27.07,14.08,24.4,18.38,1.23,-3.697,0.8277,0.0453,-0.0027,-0.07,0.83,42.78,0.5944,68.46,0.64,1.37,1503.286,1233.27,471.73,114.82,21.01,21.08,80,761.54,391.13,404.89,0.26,0.26,-74.92,77.84,304.46,4.79,7.38,34.12,391.13,114.82,0.26,7.5,0.02,0,-0.1,-0.18,-0.05
2013/02/13,10:37,546,AAN,2009/04/21,18.7,19.06,18.65,18.99,20,20.7,18.21,18.68,0.0155,0.0166,1.32,0.0707,1,0,0.1968,0.3133,795316,1152135,1384209,1392089,1413351,0.6903,0.4495,0.0473,1.16,0.87,1.16,0.85,0.4815,1,0,24,1,0,,20.7,10.07,0.8391,20.7,14.31,1.3959,18.33,16.88,16.91,0.0776,-0.0015,0.0352,0.1129,0.1113,0.159,0.0729,51.56,62.74,62.74,73.44,0.53,58.67,11113420,0.0716,40.89,26.14,14.08,23.61,17.78,0.767,-5.243,0.771,-0.0092,-0.0264,-0.18,0.65,51.56,0.6333,62.69,0.17,1.27,1528.233,1233.27,471.73,114.82,21.01,21.08,80,761.54,391.13,404.89,0.26,0.26,-74.92,77.84,304.46,4.79,7.38,34.12,391.13,114.82,0.26,7.5,0.02,0,-0.1,-0.18,-0.05
2013/02/13,10:37,547,AAN,2009/04/22,19.29,19.63,18.54,19.13,18.7,19.06,18.65,18.99,-0.0083,0.0074,-0.29,-0.0153,1,0,1.561,1.1707,1201683,1105491,1373485,1388864,1419045,1.087,0.4385,0.0474,1.33,0.9,1.33,0.88,1.2417,0,1,23,2,0,,20.7,10.07,0.8523,20.7,14.31,1.4178,18.51,16.94,16.93,0.0826,0.0005,0.0328,0.1154,0.1159,0.1603,0.0644,45.1,46.57,46.57,60.86,0.5,59.8,12315103,0.0976,49.35,25.92,23.09,26.04,16.27,0.344,-5.159,0.7289,-0.041,-0.0467,-0.2,0.5,45.1,0.6448,68.89,0.75,1.1,1539.5,1233.27,471.73,114.82,21.01,21.08,80,761.54,391.13,404.89,0.26,0.26,-74.92,77.84,304.46,4.79,7.38,34.12,391.13,114.82,0.26,7.5,0.02,0,-0.1,-0.18,-0.05
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In spite of the documentation that says empty entries are mapped to the value `0`, LOAD DATA INFILE in fact doesn't handle empty entries.  They must either have a value appropriate to the column's data type, or else the sequence `\N` to signify NULL.

See bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64603

To fix this, you could substitute `\N` for empty entries with a sed command (or whatever equivalent text substitution tool you use on Windows).

See also [MySQL load NULL values from CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data)

Comment: Also `lines terminated by '\r\n'` can make a difference if using Windows, https://stackoverflow.com/a/39238773/80772

Comment: @eelghEEz, thanks for the tip. But frankly, I haven't used Windows as a database server or client for years.

Comment: On windows using mysql workbench, I had issue that last field was throwing this error, yet data was in table. Adding '\r\n' as commented by @ eelghEEz fixed issue