# Getting a "data truncated for column" warning in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

I recently updated a table in mysql with a new column.

The new column is: `varchar(13), Null YES, Key UNI, Default NULL`.

Everything else is unchanged.  I am attempting to import data from a CSV file.  I do this all the time with no issues.  Since I updated this table however, I am getting a warning.

Below is an example line from my CSV file.

```
3517,180880CZ-075,0,0,0,5700302496246
```

The command I am using is the same as I always use:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/FILEPATH' 
INTO TABLE tablename 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6);
```

The sixth column is the new one.

When I run the mysql command, it appears to work... the data looks like it gets entered okay... but it is saying that there are warnings.  When I "SHOW WARNINGS" I get the same message for each line. "data truncated"

I double checked my file, and that last column is 13 characters long.

Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong to receive these warnings?  I've searched, but can't seem to find the answer.  I'm sure its something very obvious!

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that the lines are actually terminated `\r\n` and not `\n`, so MySQL thinks the trailing `\r` is part of the column and is having to truncate it in order to fit the string into `varchar(13)`.  Try inspecting the file with a hex editor.

Comment: Is the number of rows affected/inserted correct? I have seen cases where the delimiter or line break are wrong, which means what gets into one of the columns is not the value you intended...

Comment: `VARCHAR(13)` is extremely stingy. Why not open it up to `VARCHAR(255)`?

Comment: @tadman: Then again, it looks like it's an integer—so perhaps `BIGINT UNSIGNED` or somesuch would be an even better fit?

Comment: @tadman I guess it was because that entry will always have exactly 13 characters.  I was trying to be precise.  Best practice just to go with a bigger number?

Comment: The storage difference between `VARCHAR(13)` and `VARCHAR(255)` for strings of the same length is zero, they're identical. The higher limit means you're less likely to experience frustrating truncation bugs if you're getting data that's a tiny bit bigger than expected. Those digits might roll over one day and become 14 characters long. What will you do then?

Comment: I made the change to VARCHAR(255) and it did not give any warnings.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the line
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
with this
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'

Comment: It's rather poor etiquette to take someone's comment and post the advice it contains as your own answer.

Comment: Ok changed it from suggestion to answer. If a problem has one solution then two persons can comment same thing.

Comment: I didn't say you can't do it.  I just said it's poor etiquette.

Comment: Ok So should I delete this post?

Comment: It's up to you and your conscience.  Another possibility would be to make the post "[community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts)".

Comment: I do not have enough reputation points to post it as a comment.