# MySQL insert from file with default values

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert into sql from a csv file.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "file.csv"
INTO TABLE table_name
FIELDS TERMINATED BY " "
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
(
    id,
    name
);
```

My csv has the format:

```
123 Bob
```

or:

```
124
```

I want to have a default name for the case where the name isn't present.  I set up the column to have a default value:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD COLUMN name
varchar(255)
DEFAULT 'jerry';
```

However, when I run the insert, it is just putting empty values into the name column

Comment: Duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate o
[MySQL load NULL values from CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data).

You have to use **`\N`**  to get the null values in