# Send null if key does not exists

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, csv

I have csv files what i parse to array and pass to mysql table.
Some CSV files does not contains some columns what are in database and when i convert it to array than i have smaller number of columns that are in table and i get "syntax error".

From controller i call:

```
function sendHistoric(){
        $this->load->model('Historic_model');
        $this->load->library('csvreader');
        foreach($this->divisions as $div){
            $result =   $this->csvreader->parse_file("assets/csv/1516{$div}.csv");//path to csv file
            $this->Historic_model->loadCSVtoDB($result);
            //var_dump($result);
        }
     }
```

in model i have:

```
function loadCSVtoDB($data){
    $sql = "call ins_historic(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    foreach($data as $row){
        var_dump($row);
        $this->db->query($sql,$row);    
    }
    //echo $this->db->conn_id->error_message();
}
```

Can i somehow send **NULL** instead where he find that i have smaller number of data or i need to check if each element of array exists, if not that set it to null?

Answer (score 1):

One option to consider is not writing slower PHP looping but to harness the flexible code possibilties inside a `LOAD DATA INFILE` block, such as the processing seen in this answer link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5968530/1816093). The functions, conversions possible are endless.

Maybe 6 of one, half dozen of another. But nice for simpler routines too, and I would suggest a fast data ingest.

**Edit:** (based on OP comment below)

```
create table t62
(   c1 int not null,
    c2 varchar(10) not null,
    c3 int not null,
    c4 char(5) not null,
    someOther int not null,
    -- an addtion 57 columns here
    primary key(c1,c2,c3,c4)
);

-- Mimic the LOAD DATA INFILE or PHP loop:
insert t62(c1,c2,c3,c4,someOther) values (1,'t',1,'01742',777);
insert t62(c1,c2,c3,c4,someOther) values (1,'t',1,'01742',777); -- error 1062: Dupe PK
insert t62(c1,c2,c3,c4,someOther) values (1,'t',2,'01742',777); -- happy
```

So I don't know, how would you suggest code would pick that composite PK for you? If so, how would that made-up-data play with its relationships with other data?

Comment: I ll try like you describe, there 62 columns so i need to set each column for null if it is null...

Comment: First 4 columns are primary key, can i set some default number or string intead null for just first 4 columns using this load ?

Comment: I get

Error Number: 28000/1045

Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: YES) 

My server dont allows me to load data :S

Comment: sounds like a plain-Jane access error, not sure what you are doing. You can issue the `LOAD DATA INFILE` from inside PHP after you authenticate, if that (LOAD DATA INFILE) is what you are doing.

Comment: SOLVED by using isset for each column, stupid but works :/ 
My server provider don't allows me to use LOAD FILE.

Comment: right, it's a setting they can disable in ini / cnf