# Load Data with Null Column at the end of the row into MySql

Tags: mysql, insert, null, load-data-infile, truncated

I am having trouble loading a txt file into MySql that has a null value at the end of the row.

The txt file looks like

```
"a"|"b"|"c"|"d"|"e"|"f"|"g"|"h"|"i"
"1"|1997-09-30|"1"|1997-09-30|.01|1997-10-01|1997-09-29|"0"|
"2"|1997-10-31|"2"|1997-10-31|.02|1997-11-03|1997-10-30|"0"|1.5
"3"|1997-11-28|"3"|1997-11-28|.03|1997-12-01|1997-11-27|"0"|
```

notice the empty column at the end of the row

I am trying to insert into MySql via

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 
'C:/temp/test.txt' 
INTO TABLE test 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

I receive the error

```
`Error Code: 1265. Data truncated for column 'i' at row 1
```

Any ideas how I can insert this correctly? Accounting for the null column at the end of the row.

Comment: try adding `(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)` after `test` that will set all rows for "i" to null i think, worked for me in the past

Comment: Sorry Andriy edited the question, "i" column is not always null, so I cant just omit it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data This might help

Comment: Thanks Edwin that helped