# Issues with data transfer from Sybase (using bcp out) into MySQL (using data load)

Tags: mysql, sybase, data-migration, bcp

I have successfully exported from Sybase using bcp out. I was able to enclose all the values with "" so all my comment fields are properly covered.

The problem that I am facing is that

- All the null values from Sybase (column type nvarchar(30)) ended up in MySQL as Empty String values.
- Also having issues with moving datetime values. Sybase null datetime ended up in MySQL as '00-00-0000 00:00:00:0000'

I am using bcp out from Sybase and Data Load in MySQL

Comment: You may have to do some transformations of the data either before extracting it from the Sybase DB or before loading it into MySQL.  Take a look at this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data

Comment: Awesome thanks. That works like a majic

Comment: Great, don't forget to upvote that question and answer, and I'm going to recommend this one be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: For those looking to export from Sybase using bcp out you can use the option  -t '\",\"' -r '\"\n\"' to create a CSV format file with fields enclosed in double quotes, this will result the exported file to be as "field1","field2, value" and so on