# MySQL table broken when some values in right hand column are empty

Tags: mysql

I'm new to SQL and using it for something at work.

I have the following table I made:

```
CREATE TABLE PC_Contacts
(
POC VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
Phone_1 VARCHAR(255),
Phone_2 VARCHAR(255)
);
```

I import some data from a CSV into the table using the following command in powershell:
cmd /c 'mysql -u root -p network < CSVImport.sql'. This is what is contained within the CSVImport file:

```
USE Network
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\PC_Contacts.csv'
INTO Table PC_Contacts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS;
```

After populating the table, something I noticed is when the last column (Phone_2) doesn't have a phone number populated, instead of inputting a NULL value, it is blank. In addition, several characters on the POC column are cut off whenever a phone number is omitted. So I input xxx-xxx-xxxx into the columns, repopulated it, and everything looked clean. How can I make it so I don't have to do this and the table can just populate itself with NULL values?

```
+------------------+--------------+--------------
| POC | Phone_1 | Phone_2
+------------------+--------------+--------------
|April Wilson| 123-456-7890 | xxx-xxx-xxxx
|Anton Watson | 234-567-8901| 567-890-1234
|Ashley Walker | 345-678-9012 | 456-789-0123
```

Names and phone have been altered, of course . If I were to take xxx-xxx-xxxx out though, you would see in the POC column something like 'lson' instead of the full name. Any thoughts?

Comment: You could try to write a condition in your populating query that replaces blanks with nulls

Answer (score 0):

This bit of code , found from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data), should solve your problem I think.It will check each value and if its not present assign '' to it.

To me it seem what is happening is when a value is missing in PC_Contacts.csv the import gets confused and that is why you get some data trimed off the other columns.

```
USE Network
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.7\\Uploads\\PC_Contacts.csv'
INTO Table PC_Contacts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@vone, @vtwo, @vthree, @vfour, @vfive)
SET
POC = nullif(@vone,''),
Phone_1 = nullif(@vtwo,''),
Phone_2 = nullif(@vthree,'')
;
```

Comment: See above ^ Just added in contacts of CSV import.

Comment: Try this out its from a similar problem , it should solve your problem . If it does not work you might want to take a look at the ENCLOSED BY '"' , part cause if some values in your file are enclosed in " and some are not it can cause problems .

Comment: Unfortunately, did not work. I found out I am looking in the wrong place though. Moving to this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35167420/mysql-issue-when-importing-specific-csv-files-with-blank-values-in-random-rows