# MySQL Load Null Values from CSV data Error Code 1582

Tags: mysql, csv, null

I am trying to use the code seen in this example here:

[MySQL load NULL values from CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data)

I am using this code (Which works when I don't use the last three lines)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Myfiles/Products.csv'
INTO TABLE tblProducts
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(product_id, manufacturer, sku, pname, price, @vstock, @vcategory_id, lf_code)
Set 
stock = ifnull(@vstock = ''),
category_id = ifnull(@vcategory_id = '');
```

However, I keep getting the Error Code 1582: "Incorrect parameter count in the native function call 'ifnull' " Can someone explain what is going wrong?

Comment: ifnull(@vcategory_id,'')

Comment: OMG LOL I just spent an hour trying to figure that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should beusing `NULLIF()`, not `IFNULL()`. It takes two arguments: an expression to return in the normal case, and something else to compare with it, and it returns `NULL` if they're equal. You don't write `=` between them.

```
stock = nullif(@vstock, ''),
category_id = nullif(@vcategory_id, '');
```