# Insert NULL in Google Cloud SQL using CSV import

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I am importing CSV files into Google Cloud SQL using its import functionality. It allows to import data into a Cloud SQL table.

API reference: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/admin-api/v1beta4/instances/import

If I use a CSV row with empty values, like:

```
,,,,42,,
```

I am getting `0` values in the SQL table.
I would like to get `NULL` values instead. Is it possible ?

Comment: Actually, my question applies to several languages and can be replicated using Google Cloud UI alone. So, is a code snippet going to be helpful ?

Comment: Hi @JoseKilo, did you manage to solve this? Any 2018 updates?

Comment: Not really. It's been a while. I think I ended up changing the way I generated my CSVs. Sorry. I would try something like this (I think this functionality is/was based on MySQL LOAD DATA) https://stackoverflow.com/a/2675493/2452074
But I think I already tried that back in the day.

Comment: Update from 2022 and using postgres w/ CloudSQL. Empty columns are interpreted as null. E.g. `"id",,"some val"` would be copied as `["id", NULL, "some val"]`

Answer (score 0):

I found it to work using `NULL` as a field value:

```
"gid://Customer/10031988754",0,0,"GBP","[]","GB"
"gid://Customer/1003793973310",0,NULL,NULL,"[]","GB"
```

this was unexpected, since CSV export generates entries with `"N` as NULL