# MemSQL support for MySQL style user variables in the load data command

Tags: singlestore

Does MemSQL support user variables in the load data command, similar to MySQL (see [MySQL load NULL values from CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data) for examples)? The MemSQL documentation (https://docs.memsql.com/docs/load-data) doesn't give a clue, and my attempts at using user variables have failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, variables in LOAD DATA are not currently supported in general (as of MemSQL 5.5).  This is a feature we are tracking for a future release.

We only support the following syntax to skip the contents of a column in the file using a dummy variable (briefly mentioned in the docs https://docs.memsql.com/docs/load-data):

```
load data infile 'foo.tsv' into table foo (bar, @, @, baz);
```