# How to use null as default value on a mysql decimal field with LOAD DATA?

Tags: mysql

I load a `CSV` file using `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`. Some values eg for `decimals` are optional and thus not set in csv.

I tried both inserting a blank `,,` in csv, and a `,null,`. For both of them the `mysql` table shows a `0` as decimal value.

```
CREATE TABLE `my_table` (
     ...
    `price` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

But why isn't the default value used if I leave the field blank during load?

Sidenote: the linked question is **not** an answer, as the comment accepted has nothing to do with the special null handling in mysql! Moreover, an acceptable answer to that question should state the solution as a oneliner, so everyone finds a quick solution. Which is also not the case in the linked "duplciate" question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL load NULL values from CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data)

Comment: No, it's not....

Answer (score 0):

Found it: mysql is case sensitive here and expects a uppercase `,NULL,`. Or `,\N,`