# Load multiple NULL values into unique column

Tags: mysql, null, insert, load, unique

I noticed that I can insert multiple NULL values into a table with a UNIQUE key :

```
INSERT INTO table (autoincrementkey, uniquekey, id) VALUES (NULL, NULL, 0), (NULL, NULL, 1), (NULL, NULL, 2)
```

This works fine as I get the 3 lines inserted (and yes, the uniquekey is NULL = Yes)

However, when I try to use the Load Data from a file with the same query, it only inserts 1 NULL value, which is the first.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $file.csv INTO TABLE table FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
```

Is there any way I can insert multiple NULL values on a UNIQUE column, with the LOAD DATA INTO please ?

Thanks in advance!

=============

**[UPDATE]**

I noticed that uniquekey gets a 0 instead of a NULL, which is why only the 1st entry gets to the database.
In the CSV file it looks like this :

```
,,1
,,2
,,3
```

But uniquekey is set to NULL by default, I don't get why it gets 0 :

```
ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `uniquekey ` `uniquekey ` INT(10) DEFAULT NULL;
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

OK I got it!!
I thought (,,1) would insert NULL, NULL, 1.
But it's not true, it has to be (NULL,NULL,1) to get what you see.

Comment: Please add some sample data. I doubt you are inserting `null`, but you are probably inserting the string `'null'` (as if you would insert `null`, it should work).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! When I export my .csv file (the query contains NULL), in the file I have data like this : 
,,0
,,1
So it should be NULL since by default the value of uniquekey is NULL

Comment: Well, what you think should happen and what actually happens can be two different things, especially with `null`. See e.g. [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-null.html) (the part starting with "When reading data with LOAD DATA INFILE,"). You can use `\N` to mark nulls, or use the method described in [MySQL load NULL values from CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2675323/6248528) (or something similar).

Comment: I've just updated my first post : Both NULL and \N gets me a 0 instead of NULL for uniquekey, that's why I only get the first entry and not the rest. Any idea why it sets uniquekey to 0 ? I know it's an INT but the default value should be NULL