# Load NULL values INT

Tags: mysql, sql, load

FIY:

- I'm working with a CVS file from Census - FactFinder
- Using MySQL 5.7
- OS is Windows 10 PRO

So, I created this table:

```
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field    | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| SERIALNO | bigint(13) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| DIVISION | int(9)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| PUMA     | int(4)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| REGION   | int(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ST       | int(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ADJHSG   | int(7)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ADJINC   | int(7)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| FINCP    | int(6)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| HINCP    | int(6)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| R60      | int(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| R65      | int(1)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+----------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

And tried to load data using:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/Housing_Illinois.csv"
INTO TABLE housing
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

It didn`t work as this message appear:

> ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'FINCP' at
> row 2

The row the error message is referring to is:

> 2012000000051,3,104,2,17,1045360,1056030,,8200,1,1

I believed FINCP which is the blank value ,, right before 8200 is the problem. So I followed this thread instructions: [MySQL load NULL values from CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data)

And updated my code to:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE "C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads/Housing_Illinois.csv"
INTO TABLE housing
CHARACTER SET latin1
COLUMNS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(@SERIALNO, @DIVISION, @PUMA, @REGION, @ST, @ADJHSG, @ADJINC, @FINCP, @HINCP, @R60, @R65)
SET
SERIALNO = nullif(@SERIALNO,''),
DIVISION = nullif(@DIVISION,''),
PUMA = nullif(@PUMA,''),
REGION = nullif(@REGION,''),
ST = nullif(@ST,''),
ADJHSG = nullif(@ADJHSG,''),
ADJINC = nullif(@ADJINC,''),
FINCP = nullif(@FINCP,''),
HINCP = nullif(@HINCP,''),
R60 = nullif(@R60,''),
R65 = nullif(@R65,'');
```

The first error is now gone but this message appears:

> ' for column 'R65' at row 12t integer value: '

The row at which this message is referring to is:

> 2012000000318,3,1602,2,17,1045360,1056030,,,,

There's no error message so I don't know what exactly is the problem. I can only assume that the problem is that there are four consecutive blank values.

Another tip, if I use CSV and change all blank to 0 the code goes smoothly, but I`m not a fan or editing raw data so I would like to know other options.

Bottom line, I have two questions:

1. Shouldn`t data be loaded with the first code as MySQL should take ,, as null and 0 a plain 0?
2. What's the problem I'm getting now that I'm using SERIALNO = nullif(@SERIALNO,'')

I want to be able to differentiate between 0 and null/blank values.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have access to a text editor with regex capabilities?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  I can use Edit Pad Lite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL's `LOAD DATA` tool interprets `\N` as being a `NULL` value.  So, if your troubled row looked like this:

```
2012000000318,3,1602,2,17,1045360,1056030,\N,\N,\N,\N
```

then you might not have this problem.  If you have access to a regex replacement tool, you may try searching for the following pattern:

```
(?<=^)(?=,)|(?<=,)(?=,)|(?<=,)(?=$)
```

Then, replace with `\N`.  This should fill in all the empty slots with `\N`, which semantically will be interpreted by MySQL as meaning `NULL`.  Note that if you were to *write* a table out from MySQL, then nulls would be replaced with `\N`.  The issue is that your data source and MySQL don't know about each other.