# MYSQL import literal NULL into a numeric filed

Tags: mysql

I created the following table in MySQL.

```
CREATE TABLE person (ID int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
age float DEFAULT NULL,
spouse smallint(6) DEFAULT NULL)
```

and I tried to populate this table with an existing txt file. While most the  age and spouse values are numerical, there are few records with the value for these two fields as literal NULL.
for example

```
[1,1,NULL]
[2,Null,10]
```

Then the final result for this table becomes

```
[1,1,0]
[2,0,10]
```

It seems it turns literal NULL in the txt file into 0 in my SQL dataset. Does anyone know how to fix this problem: for the literal null, I just want it to turn the null value in SQL dataset. Many thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to populate this table using load data Infile?

Comment: Yes, I use load data local infile

Comment: You can use `nullif` in your query, explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data

Comment: The solution provided by @SimranjitSingh should help you resolve your problem. The thing to remember is that a string with a value of "NULL" is not the same as NULL data.

Comment: It worked. thank you all!