# LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE from fputcsv: data not recorded

Tags: php, mysql, csv, load-data-infile, fputcsv

I have below CSV file: (3 columns)

```
998877665544331,,baba
998877665544332,,
998877665544333,,
998877665544334,,test
998877665544335,,
,R32AS00ZZYY,
998877665544337,,
998877665544338,,
998877665544339,,asfd
998877665544330,,
,R32AS00XXYY,
,R32AS00XXZZ,
```

I store it as file by: `fputcsv($fp, array($data0, $data1, $data2));`

then i want to store it in DB with this query:

```
$query = sprintf(
        "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '%s' 
        INTO TABLE devices 
        FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
        OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
        LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
        (col0, col1, col2);", addslashes(storage_path('app/file.csv')));

$asdf = DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec($query);
```

problem/question:

1. why it only store first record and 6th record?
   like below:

   ```
   +--+----------------+-------------+--------+------+
   |id| col0           | col1        | col xx | col2 |
   +--+----------------+-------------+--------+------+
   |01|998877665544331 | ""          | NULL   | baba |
   |02| ""             | R32AS00ZZYY | NULL   | ""   |
   +--+----------------+-------------+--------+------+
   ```

what I try to achieve: stored all of data accordingly

EDIT: my table definition:

```
/*Table structure for table `tabel_name` */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tabel_name`;

CREATE TABLE `tabel_name` (
  `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `col0` VARCHAR(16) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col1` VARCHAR(12) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `colxx` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `col2` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tabel_col0_unique` (`col0`),
  UNIQUE KEY `tabel_col1_unique` (`col1`)
) ENGINE=INNODB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined col1 as unique:

```
  UNIQUE KEY `tabel_col1_unique` (`col1`)
```

And your data has non-unique values:

```
998877665544331,,baba
998877665544332,,
```

So the first row gets inserted, but then the second fails because of the unique constraint.

Comment: oh gosh, that make sense,,, is there a way to keep it as null if not exist? or empty string?

Comment: It's already inserting as empty string. I'm not sure offhand if that load-from-csv feature of MySQL can be told to insert as NULL instead, you'd have to check the docs.

Comment: (Also not sure offhand if MySQL allows multiple NULL values for a field constrained unique, but maybe?)

Comment: Hah, thanks, it partially solved with: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data