# MySQL NULL in last CSV column possible

Tags: mysql

I want to import CSV files into MySQL 5.7 and would like to load NULL values.

I have read [MySQL load NULL values from CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675323/mysql-load-null-values-from-csv-data)

If I use the same sample table and data it works fine.
If I however try to import the following data:

```
1,2,3
1,2,3,4,
1,2,3,4,5
```

Then the output is: `Error Code: 1366. Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'five' at row 2`

Table creation script:

```
create table moo(
one int not null,
two int not null,
three int null,
four int null,
five int null);
```

I am using the nullif expression for the nullable columns:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/test-moo.txt' INTO TABLE moo 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    (one, two, @vthree, @vfour, @vfive)
    SET three = nullif(@vthree,''),
    four = nullif(@vfour,''),
    five =nullif(@vfive,'');
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? It only seems to go wrong with the last column.

Comment: Are you sure that the error doesn't come from the first line "1,2,3" should be "1,2,3,,"

Comment: Yes I am sure. Removing this line will change the error message to indicate that row 1 is faulty. What I just also found is that if I make line 2 the last line of the file, then it works. It seems that there is something going wrong with the end of line interpretation.

Comment: I tried it with MySQL-MariaBD (15.1 Distrib 10.1.37-MariaDB), and it worked. So maybe it's bug in your MySQL-Version. Or, more likely, maybe you have some invisible characters in your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question/problem. It seems that the line separator was not correctly. I am working on Windows environment, and so it should have been **\r\n** instead of **\n**.

So after correcting it became this, and processed correctly:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/test-moo.txt' INTO TABLE moo 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
    (one, two, @vthree, @vfour, @vfive)
    SET three = nullif(@vthree,''),
    four = nullif(@vfour,''),
    five =nullif(@vfive,'');
```