# IS NULL and IS NOT NULL in SQL query not working

Tags: mysql, null

I am new to MySQL. I created an Excel file, then saved it in CSV notepad format. The file contains some NULL values in age column. Then I imported that table into one of my existing schemas. Now when I am running query as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mavenmovies.sql2 WHERE rep_age IS NULL;
```

it's not returning any rows. And when I am running query as:

```sql
SELECT * FROM mavenmovies.sql2 WHERE rep_age IS NOT NULL;
```

it's returning all the rows that include the rows containing NULL values in `rep_age`. I checked and there is no space in the NULL cells. I don't understand why?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Apparently `rep_age` is `varchar`, and, depending on what you had in the CSV, either an empty string `''` or a string `'NULL'` was imported. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/2675493/11683.

Comment: Execute: `SELECT rep_age, length(rep_age) FROM mavenmovies.sql2` to check the length of each value.

Answer (score 0):

You can check by using

```
SELECT COALESCE(SIGN(LENGTH(rep_age)),0) as rep_age, COUNT(*) as count
  FROM mavenmovies.sql2 
 GROUP BY COALESCE(SIGN(LENGTH(rep_age)),0)
```

existence and count of `null` and `non-null` values, where if `SIGN()` function returns 1, then count means number of `non-null` values of `rep_age` columns, otherwise for `null` values.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=203875364d8bbb9303faed8a17872acc)</kbd>