# Load Data Infile Error with date

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqlimport

I am trying to load a .csv file that has 5 columns into a table that has the same corresponding columns plus a PK. Dates are data type DATE and all others are Varchar(), except PK.

Here is my load data Import:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Events_Upload.csv'
INTO TABLE db.events
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
Ignore 1 lines
(
Event_Name,
Event_Handle,
Create_Date,
Retire_Date,
Event_Desc
)
```

The error is :

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '' for column 'Retire_Date' at row 1
```

Row one  in CSV looks like:

**Time to Send Survey,SurvESend,2013-04-10,,Time for the system to send out the Esurveys**

How can I make this field NULL and not blank for uploading from CSV?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing as null in CSV file. What you can do is may be provide some default value for the missing column and replace it with null by the query after insertion into the table.

Or you can have a look at [skipping-empty-csv-objects](http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2012/12/04/skipping-empty-csv-objects/)

check this [Export null to .csv](https://stackoverflow.com/q/664406/2006839) and https://superuser.com/questions/390031/how-to-write-null-into-csv-from-excel-for-blank-fields